# Products Add To Compare link does the job but redirects to wrong url cause of AJAX call

Tags: ajax, magento

I'm writing a custom module for displaying various kind of products which can be loaded with AJAX.

So i'm calling one of my controllers methods which then echoes html populated by block. That's all fine ...

The problem occurs when after products Add To Compare link Magento redirects me back to last controller method called instead of page my module is added.

Is there any neat way to fix this behavior instead of overwriting addAction()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that through an observer that hooks on the `postDispatch` of the compare controller. Create your own module. Let's call it `Easylife_Compare` with the following files:
**`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Compare.xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Compare>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Compare>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Compare/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Compare>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Compare>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models><!-- declar your own models-->
            <easylife_compare>
                <class>Easylife_Compare_Model</class>
            </easylife_compare>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_compare_add><!-- observe the post dispatch for adding to compare list -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_compare>
                        <model>easylife_compare/observer</model>
                        <method>stopRedirect</method>
                    </easylife_compare>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_compare_add>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Compare/Model/Observer.php` - your own observer

```
<?php
class Easylife_Compare_Model_Observer{
    public function stopRedirect($observer){
        //get the real referrer from server var
        $referrer = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
        if ($referrer){
            //set your new redirect
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($referrer);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and give it a go. This should work on the 'normal' version, without products retrieved by ajax and in your case.